# PredicateBuilder null check not added to query

Tags: c#, linq, predicatebuilder, linqkit

I have a situation where I want to query an accounts table. I want all accounts except accounts where `ParentId != null` as default.

I have tried the following with the predicate builder, but it does not take effect in the sql query. Any idea how to add the `whereClause.And(a => a.ParentId != null);` check when using the LinqKit PredicateBuilder?

```
 var whereClause = PredicateBuilder.New<VAccount>(true);

 whereClause = whereClause.And(a => a.ParentId != null); // Not added to query

 if (dto.OrganisationId != 0)
    whereClause = whereClause.Or(a => a.OrganisationId == dto.OrganisationId);
 
 // Other search inputs added etc..
```

Comment: Maybe because you have used `Or` later?

Comment: Why are you using `And` & `Or` after each other? I think this blocks out you will probably need nest the `Or` inside the `And`

Comment: You guys are right about `And` and `Or` after each other is not working. I have changed my approach by filtering all accounts like `accounts.Where(a => a.ProfileId != null)` before running it through the predicatebuildere where clauses. Just consious about that could have a performance hit..

Comment: Are you working with EF? Then no performance hit.

Comment: Yes I´m working with EF. Thanks for the info.